# Extract Tags From HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, url, extract

I want to get the source of an image from html block and put it in a variable to send it to a remote function.
How can i extract img tag from html text :

Answer (score 2):

```
var myImageSrc = document.getElementById('myImageId').src;
```

or similar.

Comment: i want to exract it from rss feed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    var img=imgs[i];
    //do something with img.src
}
```

-- edit --

to remove images from the text do something like this (at the comment):

```
img[i].parentNode.removeChild(img[i])
```

What's left is the text (access it using `img[i].parentNode.innerHTML`)

Comment: i want to exract it from rss feed.
i store my rss feed in a variable then i want to personalised : it's text content and images i want to seperate images and the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageSource = document["yourImage"].src;
```

Comment: i want to exract it from rss feed.
i store my rss feed in a variable then i want to personalised : it's text content and images i want to seperate images and the text.